# Get previous value in linq loop?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, c#-4.0

I am trying to convert the code below to a shorthand linq, but not sure if it is possible. Is there a more elegant way to do this using Linq? The complication occurs is that it is a nested loop to split the AllowedRoles and checking each one if it IsUserInRole.

```
   bool allowed = RoleManager.IsUserUnrestricted(userId);
    if (!allowed)
    {
        foreach (var item in element.AllowedRoles.Split(','))
        {
            if (roleManager.IsUserInRole(userId, item.Trim()))
            {
                allowed = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    if (allowed)
    {
        AddWidget(element.Name);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
if (RoleManager.IsUserUnrestricted(userId)
||  element.AllowedRoles.Split(',')
           .Any(item => roleManager.IsUserInRole(userId, item.Trim()))) {
    ...
}
```

The idea is to use LINQ's `Any` function to find the first matching item without a loop.

Comment: Almost identical answer, you got me by 1 minute :-)

Comment: @MikeKulls We're lucky Jon Skeet is asleep, he'd be ahead of both of us by three to four minutes :)

Answer (score 2):

You could use something like this:

```
element.AllowedRoles.Split(',').Any(r => roleManager.IsUserInRole(userId, r.Trim()))
```

BTW, I don't see a nested loop, there is only one loop in the code you posted. Do you have a collection of elements? Also, why is the title of your question "Get previous value in linq loop?" I don't see a need for this anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

something like this?

```
if(RoleManager.IsUserUnrestricted(userId) || element.AllowedRoles.Split(',').Any(r=> roleManager.IsUserInRole(userId,r.Trim()))
{
        AddWidget(element.Name);
}
```